# How to write unit tests for a Slack Bolt application?

Tags: unit-testing, slack

I'm attempting to transition an app from the hubot library to the official @slack/bolt library.  The app uses hubot-test-helper for unit testing, which mocks out a chatroom.  Is there anything equivalent for the bolt library?

Yes, most of the logic can be (and in many cases is) split away from the actual chat implementation; the exception being middleware which I believe still benefits from testing closer to integration.